# bash script: error in conditional statement

Tags: bash

What is wrong with the below script?

```
if [ $# -eq 0 -o $1 = "-h" -o $1 = "--help" ]; then    ## line no: 11
    echo $usage
    exit 0;
fi
```

If run without any arguments, it gives the below error

```
% ./test.sh
./test.sh: line 11: [: too many arguments
```

Comment: You should quote your variables, particularly `$1` in this case. May I recommend http://www.shellcheck.net ?

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using `-o` you can use `||` to do short-circuit evaluation, i.e., if a condition is true the subsequent conditions won't be evaluated.

```
if [ -z "$1" ] || [ "$1" = '-h' ] || [ "$1" = '--help' ]; then
    echo "$usage"
    exit 0
fi
```

If you're only running this script in bash you can do use this more compact syntax:

```
if [[ -z "$1" || "$1" = '-h' || "$1" = '--help' ]]; then
    echo "$usage"
    exit 0
fi
```

but that may not work in other shells.

Note that I've also quoted the argument to `echo`. In general, you should quote parameters unless you explicitly want word splitting. I guess I ought to mention that `printf` is more robust than `echo`, but `echo` is ok for fixed strings.

Answer (score 0):

You have to quote `$1` because if it's empty and not quoted, it will be replaced by literally nothing instead of and empty string

```
if [ $# -eq 0 -o "$1" = "-h" -o "$1" = "--help" ]; then
    echo $usage
    exit 0;
fi
```